# Is it possible to get mac address by Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want my extension be able to send the users' physical mac address to a server.

Is there any to get the the client mac address in a Chrome extension?

Comment: No. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15554299/how-do-you-get-the-device-name-or-hostname-from-a-chrome-extension and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454858/how-to-get-client-mac-address-by-a-access-on-a-website for discussion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With an extension it is definitely not possible.

The closest you can get is the IP addresses and all network interfaces via the [chrome.system.network](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/system_network) API that is available to chrome apps - but that doesn't include the MAC address, as of Chrome 33.

---

We solved the problem with an external command (`.cmd` on windows, `.sh` on linux) that we call via the native messaging API. The external script simply outputs the current MAC address.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what that external command looks like and how you used Native Messaging API to call it?

Comment: @cweiske can you provide more details as how you implemented that.

Comment: Would it still work with current state of chrome extensions (mv3)?